# How to change body attribute in jest?

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write a test case for my react component. The react component is rendered if a certain attribute of body tag has a particular value. 
This is dynamically generated based on a service. How can I modify this attribute in jest so that i can render my component ?

so far i have tried this

```
window.history.pushState(
  {},
  "coolvalue",
  "coolvalue/"
);
```

and

```
// base path for coolvalue
document.body.setAttribute("data-basepath", "coolvalue");
```

both seem to not work.

Comment: Can you share the minimal code which you want to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example for modifying the `attribute` of `document.body`:

`index.ts`:

```js
export function render() {
  if (document.body.getAttribute('data-basepath') === 'coolvalue') {
    return 'My Component';
  }
  return null;
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { render } from './';

describe('render', () => {
  test('should render my component', () => {
    document.body.setAttribute('data-basepath', 'coolvalue');
    const actualValue = render();
    expect(actualValue).toBe('My Component');
  });

  it('should not render my component', () => {
    document.body.setAttribute('data-basepath', '');
    const actualValue = render();
    expect(actualValue).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58365044/index.spec.ts (8.322s)
  render
    ✓ should render my component (11ms)
    ✓ should not render my component (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.205s
```